# Does Spark-SQL on Yarn need HA(High Availability)?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, high-availability

When Spark-SQL thrift server run on Yarn(with HA),does it need HA configuration ?
Need something like zookeeper?

PS:Yarn with HA is available.